# Mun's orbit : clockwise or counter-clockwise

Tags: kerbal-space-program

when viewing Kerbin's North pole, does Mun orbit clockwise or counter-clockwise ?

I guess I could probably see for myself using timewarp, but I only have the demo, which doesn't have the feature.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you tell which way a planet rotates?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137768/how-do-you-tell-which-way-a-planet-rotates)

Comment: @MBraedley rotation != orbital direction (But I agree that that answer probably contains the simplest answer to the matter.)

Comment: @FEichinger I'd just rather not have to rewrite the answer, and since the body rotation and orbital rotation are highly correlated in real life, it's easier to answer a single question rather than two.

Answer (score 6):

Seen from over the north pole, the Mun orbits in the same direction that Kerbin rotates - counterclockwise.

Comment: This is true for all celestial bodies in KSP, by the way. The whole solar system has a counter-clockwise spin.